# Sharing elements between activity and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, shared-element-transition

I tried following the shared elements transition tutorials for activities and fragments but I am in a kind of special situation here.

To simplify, I will explain my problem with a single TextView.

My problem is : I have a fragment with a recycler view holding data and displayed using a simple TextView. When I click on this TextView, I open a fragment which uses the same string contained in the latter text view. What I would like to do is share the TextView between the activity and the created fragment. Here is the code I use to create the fragment and share the elements :

```
    forumView = ForumView.newInstance(forumId);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        forumView.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new AutoTransition());
        ArticleAdapter.HomeCardViewHolder holder = (ArticleAdapter.HomeCardViewHolder) mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);

        View forumPic = holder.getCardPhoto();
        forumPic.setTransitionName("forum picture");
        View forumName = holder.getArticleTitle();
        forumName.setTransitionName("forum name");

        forumView.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new AutoTransition());
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.forum_fragment_slide_in, R.anim.forum_fragment_slide_out, R.anim.forum_fragment_slide_in, R.anim.forum_fragment_slide_out)
                .addSharedElement(forumPic, "forum picture")
                .addSharedElement(forumName, "forum name")
                .add(R.id.forum_fragment_receiver, forumView)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
```

Despite setting the right transition name, the share animation does not happen. I am wondering if this is even possible actually.

Does anyone knows if this is possible ? or should I put everything from my activity into a fragment and then share elements between the two fragments ? or anything else actually.

Thanks for your replies, I hope someone can help me.